# What's the proper way to change Android notification color?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm trying to customize the background color of Android notification

[image]

As you can see, I want the change the background of the whole area marked by the red marker to be red. There are some gray spaces left. How to fix this?

Here's my code, BTW (tested on Pixel 3 running Android 12):

**NotificationUtil.kt**

```
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.widget.RemoteViews
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import kotlin.random.Random

class NotificationUtil (private val context: Context) {

    fun showNotification(title: String, message: String) {
        val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
        )

        val channelId = context.getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id)
        val remoteView = RemoteViews(context.packageName,  R.layout. custom_notification_layout )
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.holo_red_dark))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        notificationBuilder.setContent(remoteView)

        val notificationManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                channelId,
                "Default Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            )
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        notificationManager.notify(Random.nextInt(), notificationBuilder.build())
    }

}
```

**custom_notification_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8" ?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id = "@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height = "64dp"
    android:background = "@color/colorAccent"
    android:padding = "10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id = "@+id/image"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart = "true"
        android:layout_marginEnd = "10dp"
        android:src = "@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/title"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf = "@id/image"
        android:textColor = "#000"
        android:textSize = "13sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/text"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_below = "@id/title"
        android:layout_toEndOf = "@id/image"
        android:ellipsize = "marquee"
        android:singleLine = "true"
        android:textColor = "#000"
        android:textSize = "13sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't in Android 12, it's one of the behavior changes:

> Android 12 changes the appearance and behavior of fully custom notifications. Previously, custom notifications were able to use the entire notification area and provide their own layouts and styles. This resulted in anti-patterns that could confuse users or cause layout compatibility issues on different devices.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12

Comment: Very restrictive design :/